# How to get Nautilus to "Open with Archive Mounter"?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, nautilus

I see Ubuntu screenshots showing that one can right-click an ISO, and have an option to "Open with Archive Mount". How do I get that running elsewhere where it isn't default (Debian in my case)? This is so as to avoid having to use the command-line to loop-mount it.

Note that I use GNOME **2.30**.

Comment: What is the GNOME version on your Debian system?  I couldn't find any Nautilus/GNOME plugin on my Ubuntu system which provides this, so probably it's just built-in into newer versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this feature request which suggests that it is part of the nautilus package: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=529297

I found the file "mount-archive.desktop" at: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/natty/nautilus/natty/annotate/head:/debian/mount-archive.desktop

On my Ubuntu PC it is at /usr/share/applications/mount-archive.desktop

Comment: On my Ubuntu PC it is at /usr/share/applications/mount-archive.desktop